# Receiving messages from multiple accounts

Tags: javascript, discord

I am working on a BetterDiscord plugin that allows you to receive and send messages from several accounts in a single instance of Discord via tokens. Assuming the user already has the token, how might I go about receiving and sending messages under another token, with say a context menu option?

Comment: Your question isn't clear as to what you mean by "single instance of Discord".    Each instance of the Client object must be logged in with a single token, however, there is nothing restricting you from creating multiple client objects in a single application.  You just have to keep track of them with separate variable names, or perhaps an array.

Comment: Yes, that is my question. How do you login as multiple clients in a single discord instance. The goal is to receive and send messages under different accounts without having to switch between them.

Comment: Could you maybe go into a little more detail on how to do that?

Comment: @xero-lib Just to clarify, you've tagged the question with `discord.js` (a javascript library to make discord bots) but you're actually attempting to make a BetterDiscord plugin (which has no relation at all to discord.js). Is that correct?

Comment: Good question, I've had the same myself many times. Are you using Discord.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To utilize multiple clients you simply create them as separate instances:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const tokenA = 'SomeToken';
const tokenB = 'SomeOtherToken';

const clientA = new Discord.Client();
const clientB = new Discord.Client();

clientA.login(tokenA);
clientB.login(tokenB);
```

Keep in mind you have to configure both clients for things such as commands/aliases as well as adding handlers for events on both.  They will act as independent bots.

Comment: Yes but how might you go about switching between used tokens without restarting the app? As well as having a listener for incoming messages simultaneously.

Comment: There is no need to switch.  If you want clientA you reference that.  If you want clientB, you reference it instead.  I suggest making your methods take the client as a parameter in order to reuse code.

Comment: Ah, thank you. Could you possibly demonstrate how one might send a message using a token? I am a slight bit stuck on that part.

Comment: @xero-lib Discord.js is not integrated with BetterDiscord. Discord.js is a node module, Discord is running Chromium with browser JS. You can't send a message using discord.js in a BetterDiscord plugin.

Comment: Oh, I'm not using pure discord.js, I'm just trying to find a way to do it.

Comment: Yes, I didn't catch that due to tags, can you clarify.  My answer may not be appropriate for what you are attempting to do.

Comment: I am trying to find a way to listen for incoming messages and send outgoing messages (by any means necessary) using a token.

Comment: @xero-lib I mean that `discord.js` as a name (discord dot js) is the name of a module you run on a Node.js server to host a bot, it has virtually no relation at all to BetterDiscord plugins or writing Discord plugins in JS

Comment: Well, I figured running a local bot in a BetterDiscord environment would be a useful way to go about doing what I'm doing here.

Comment: Specifically how would you continuously listen for new messages on a specific token while being logged in with another, and how to send a message under one token while being technically logged in as another.

Comment: My idea is to use a local discord.js bot that will read a message input as a command  and then send a message as that account for you, but I don't know how I would go about doing that.

Comment: Alright, well this answer was specifically for the originally tagged discord.js, not BetterDiscord.  I'm not familiar with BetterDiscord (first time I've heard of it).  You should update your question to be a bit more clear on your request.

Comment: Well BetterDiscord just runs JavaScript plugins. The main question I'm asking here is how do you send a message using a token, and how do you listen for messages using a token. To my knowledge a bot can do this.

Comment: Gotcha. I think it would avoid confusion if you added those details to your question, because now you need to log in to a user account with a webpacked build of discord.js (userbotting is a bannable offense btw) somehow in a context where the userbot will log in and out along with the main user in a betterdiscord plugin (also bannable actually). If you get that working you just need a reference to that logged-in client and you can send messages on it with just `client.channels.get("id").send("msg")`

Comment: Listening to messages and sending messages are the most basic of features if you have discord.js working. Just google for any discord.js guides.

Comment: Awesome, thank you.

Comment: @Klaycon Well said.